# If condition on multiple column variables, Power bi

Tags: if-statement, powerbi

I am trying to create a column or measure based on below condition. Thanks in advance.

-- when date is maximum and status is closed return "close" for the shipment for all dates and if  max date has "Open" as status return "Open" for all dates for that shipments.
[image]